# How to install packages using pip through corporate proxy with configuration script?

Tags: python, ssl, pip

I am not able to install any packages using pip. I'm behind a corporate proxy which is configured using a proxy script. The proxy file is in the format described [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config).

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit
Python version: 3.7.4
Pip version: 19.0.3

After reading through various other questions here on stackoverflow, I've tested different kinds of options, some of which result in different errors:

1. No extra options:

```
pip install scipy --verbose
```

```
Collecting scipy
  1 location(s) to search for versions of scipy:
  * https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/
  Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/
  Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/" in the cache
  Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/scipy/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x068AD410>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/scipy/
```

2. Setting the proxy to setting to point to the config file:

```
pip install scipy --verbose --proxy http://<redacted>.com/proxy.pac
```

```
Collecting scipy
  1 location(s) to search for versions of scipy:
  * https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/
  Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/
  Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/" in the cache
  Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/scipy/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/scipy/
```

3. Setting the trusted hosts as suggested for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

```
pip install scipy --proxy http://<redacted>.com/proxy.pac --verbose --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

...gets me the same result as before in attempt 2. How to proceed? The SSL error is strange and I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved this a bit before asking. The solution is simple:

Take the first (default) proxy from the proxy.pac file and use that as the input to pip's proxy option.